# How to run reaction callback on every possible change in MobX?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

This is my simplified store:

```
export class ProfileStore {
  profile = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Tommy",
    todos: [
      {
        value: "Clean the room",
        done: false
      }
    ]
  };

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      profile: observable,
    });
  }
}
```

My goal is to listen to every possible change inside "profile" observable.
I wanted to use `reaction` from MobX for this but it is kinda tricky.

```
reaction(
      () => this.profile,
      () => {
        console.log("change");
      }
    );
```

Above example doesn't work at all because MobX doesn't react to values but to properties and references. So I changed it to this:

```
reaction(
      () => ({
        id: this.profile.id,
        name: this.profile.name,
        todos: this.profile.todos.slice()
      }),
      () => {
        console.log("change");
      }
    );
```

And it started working but not entirely. It listened to every change besides toggling `done` property in todos. And if I add another property I would need to list in here which is kinda tedious.

**What's the best way to handle this problem? How to react to every possible change?**

I made a codesandbox for this: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-mobx-react-project-forked-5niu8?file=/index.js)

Try to press buttons and look at the counter.

Comment: you may try a different observable type as well -- https://doc.ebichu.cc/mobx/refguide/map.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To react for every possible change you need to dereference every property. To do that, for example, you can use `toJS` method to serialize your `profile` object. (Or even native `JSON.stringify`):

```
import { reaction, toJS } from 'mobx';

// ...

    reaction(
      () => toJS(profileStore.profile),
      () => {
        setReactionCounter((state) => state + 1);
      }
    );
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69099041-k1bvq)