# MobX - Reaction inside class component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Today I started using MobX and the first problem I ran into is how to execute a function in a React class component whenever an Observable updates.

I am under the impression this can be achieved using a `reaction`, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

```js
class MissionLog {

    private _missions: Array<IMissionItem> = [];
    public get missions() {
        return this._missions;
    }

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    // Example of a method that modifies the _missions array
    public receiveMission(mission: IMissionItem) {
        this._missions.push(mission);
    }
}

export const missionLog = new MissionLog();

// Example of modifying the missions array
missionLog.receiveMission(someMission);

export const ObserverTest = observer(class _ObserverTest extends React.Component {
   
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        // Executes the console.log at the start,
        // but not when missionLog.missions changes.
        autorun(() => {
            console.log("Autorun", missionLog.missions);
        })

        // Never executes the console.log
        reaction(
            () => missionLog.missions,
            (mission) => {
                console.log("Reaction");
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // Accessing missionLog.missions here
            // gives me the correct, updated data,
            // so my setup should be fine.
        )
    }
});
```

I also tried to use `intercept` and `observe` instead of `reaction`, but also no result.

Comment: How do you modify your `missions`? Your current reaction implementation will only execute when `missions` array itself change, i.e. you reassign the array. Since you are not using any internals in the reaction, reaction won't run if you change something inside of the array.

Comment: @Danila `MissionLog` has a number of methods that modify `_missions`. Those methods get called from other parts of the application. I have added one as an example to my above code.

Comment: I see. Then yes, my initial comment was correct. Read more here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72124982/reaction-not-being-triggered-by-nested-observables/72138652#72138652 and this section of docs https://mobx.js.org/reactions.html

Comment: @Danila Thanks for those links. If I change the first parameter of reaction from `() => missionLog.missions` to `() => toJS(missionLog.missions)`, it works!

Comment: @Danila If you wanted to expand your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: This question was asked quite many times already, so I think it's better if you just upvote that other answer and maybe even close the question :) Other questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151460/mobx-observable-only-get-updated-if-i-log-it/72164497#72164497 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736329/deep-changes-of-objects-cannot-be-observed-in-mobx/70739046#70739046 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099041/how-to-run-reaction-callback-on-every-possible-change-in-mobx/69100295#69100295

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we both ran into the same problem and thats poor documentation from Mobx :-D.

Correct me if I am wrong,but according to their documentation react() acts like an useEffect function in React.

You should basically place it anywhere where you need reaction in your app.

```
reaction(() => data, (data, reaction) => { sideEffect }, options?)
```

the first argument is accepting the data, that should be changing.

```
() => data
```

the second argument is fucntion where you say what happens, if the data changes.

```
(data, reaction) => { sideEffect }
```